# Firestore rules: disable access for specific app version

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'd like to disable my app functionality for older app version. I'm thinking about the possibilities I could try, and I'm wondering if I can do it through Firestore rules, in order not to let users update the database if they don't update the app from Play Store.

Is it possible? Any other methods?
My app is developed with Flutter

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate the app entirely to a new Firebase app, then remove the old app and revoke its `firebase.json`.

Alternatively, might be a better idea to prompt users to update the app instead. It's a good idea to build in a force update screen early so you can avoid this situation altogether. Consider a boolean set using Remote Config, when toggled a force update screen is rendered. Then you can target specific app versions using Remote Config.

Comment: I'll implement the second tip in the next update for next times